# How to remove browse button in TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, php, tinymce

I want to remove the search button from a tinyMCE version 4 file, follow image:

[image]

I've tried this setting:

```
body: [{
    name: 'href',
    type: 'textbox',
    filetype: 'file',
},
```

But when I click in the "Insert Picture" action, the browse button appear normaly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove "Browse" button from TinyMCE's "Insert Link" dialog when using MoxieManager](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21477429/remove-browse-button-from-tinymces-insert-link-dialog-when-using-moxiemanag)

Comment: No my friend, I've tried this setting, but when it is the "Insert Picture" action, that setting doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem using CSS, take the "aria-label" attribute and put the **display** as **none**.

```
.mce-btn.mce-open.mce-abs-layout-item.mce-last[aria-label="Upload image"] {
    display: none; !important
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Configure your "tinymce-init.js" as follows:

```
file_browser_callback : false
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify which file pickers you want enabled via `file_picker_types` and/or `file_browser_callback_types` editor options; current options are `file, image, media`. So in your case if you want to keep the browse/search button on the Link plugin but you want it removed on the Image plugin, you'd remove just the `image` type from that list:

```js
tinymce.init({
  ...
  file_picker_types: 'file, media',
  file_browser_callback_types: 'file, media',
  ...
});
```

TinyMCE docs on these options: 
https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/file-image-upload/#file_browser_callback_types